# Can I use a React hook containing a ref without triggering the exhaustive deps lint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

Quite a particular issue.

I'm using an `isMounted` value to prevent a `useEffect` function executing. This doesn't trigger the exhaustive deps lint when it's contained within the component itself:

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }, [value]); // no exhaustive deps error

  return <div />
}
```

But if we abstract that out to a hook, like so:

```
// useIsMounted.js
export const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
  return isMounted;
};
```

```
// MyComponent.js
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }, [value]); // has exhaustive deps error

  return <div />
}
```

Then we get the linting error.

It's not the end of the world but I'd like to be able to use the linting rule and not have unnecessarily repeating code all over the place. Is there something I can do about that?

Thanks

**Edit:**
I've actually refactored slightly to use comparisons to previous values in my effect hooks instead of mount checks and it's slightly cleaner this way for my particular case. The inconsistency with the linting error described above is still odd to me though.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by tracking mounted vs not?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I'm trying to run effects only when a value has been changed. Eg: setting localStorage and getting it inside the useState init function. Also to clear user data only when the loggedIn status has changed to false.

Comment: ah ok, so in the real code there is a call to setState inside the useEffect hook.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes. I've edited above to say I've refactored slightly to not do it this way anymore, though I'm still a bit perplexed by the inconsistent linting error.